# How to config "Spring Security" for secure /admin URL but allow all another URL?

Tags: spring-mvc, security, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to configure Spring Security for secure route /admin (Allow access only for ADMIN role) but I want to allow all another route without hardcode all of the routes in my config file.

It`s my spring security program configuration:

```
  http.
        authorizeRequests()
            .mvcMatchers("/", "/login", "/registration", "/news/**").permitAll()
            .mvcMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN").anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/news/")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
        .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
        .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
```

How can I allow all routes and secure only /admin route and child?

When I changed this line of config

`.mvcMatchers("/", "/login", "/registration", "/news/**").permitAll()`

to

`.mvcMatchers("/**").permitAll()`

my /admin route became unsecured and I could open there without login.
How can do it?

Answer (score -1):

you should just change the order of mvcMatchers

```
http
.authorizeRequests().mvcMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN").anyRequest()
.authenticated().mvcMatchers("/**").permitAll()
```

after that,if you send request to "admin/~" then login form will appear 
and in the other case , all request will pass

Comment: After I change the order and fix a problem with many redirects  All of my links redirect to the login form.